# Has this (rebased) branch been merged?

Tags: git, rebase

I want to see if you've merged my branch into your branch.  But I can't just use `git branch --contains`, because you've rebased my branch on yours before doing the merge.  Still, it seems like there ought to be an easy way to verify that those changes have been pulled into your branch - is there?

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrect**

```
git branch --contains their_branch
```

This won't show the correct results, since their branch is ahead of yours.

You can still use `git branch --contains` but in the opposite fashion you're thinking of:

**Correct**

```
git branch --contains your_branch
```

If someone else rebased their branch onto yours, you should see it in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git log --graph --decorate --all
```

to see quite detail history log, this will help to you

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is:

`git log your_branch..my_branch`

This should show you a list of commits which are available only in `my_branch`. If there is no output then, voila!, `my_branch` has been completely merged into `your_branch`.

Hope this helps. :)